# deselectd other button when one button isSeleted

Tags: swift, button, deselect

I have three button link together called tipChanged .
one button was seleted by default (10%)
I want to write some code to make one button isSeleted ,the other two will automatically deseleted .my code work but too wordy ,any easy way ?
below is my code ,thanks in advance.

import UIKit

class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var zeroPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tenPctButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var twentyPctButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func tipChanged(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let pctChoosed = sender.currentTitle
    if pctChoosed == "0%"{
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = true
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
    }else if pctChoosed == "10%"{
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        tenPctButton.isSelected = true
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = false
    }else{
        zeroPctButton.isSelected = false
        tenPctButton.isSelected = false
        twentyPctButton.isSelected = true
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the if statement and just set them all to false. Then just under where they are set to false set sender.isSelected = true and you should get the desired results.